# Create a Registry and keep it alive in order to wait for new connection

Tags: java, rmi

I want to create a registry and keep it alive in order to wait for new connections. Is it possible? What I really mean is:

In application 1:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2001);
}
```

In application 2:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
MyServer server = new MyServer();
LocateRegistry.getRegistry(2001);
Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:2001/Server1", server);
}
```

I know it's a silly question , in the application 1, the createRegistry will return a registry, but I don't know how to keep it alive and wait for new connection, e.g. when i start different servers in application 2.

 Can anyone give me advices?

 Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Store the result of `createRegistry()` into a static variable. That will keep it from being garbage-collected.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I tried as you suggested, but when i ran the program in netbeans, it just shown me "run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)"

Comment: Given that none of the mode you posted displays anything, I don't know why you are expecting any other outcome.